# Get Next Iteration Value with *ngFor

Tags: angular, indexing, ngfor

I'm trying to get in the controller the value of the next iteration within an *ngFor loop:

**Template:**

```
<p *ngFor="let history of histories; let i=index; "
[ngClass]="{'show':history.date==dateseeing}">
    <span class="history-date">{{ history.date }}</span>
    <span class="history-txt">{{ history.txt }}</span>
    <mat-icon 
        *ngIf="history.date==dateseeing"
        (click)="readNext(history[i+1])">keyboard_arrow_down
    </mat-icon></p>
```

**Controller**:

```
public readNext(history) {
console.log(history);
const date = history.date;
this.dateseeing = date;}
```

Can't make it work

Comment: You cannot do that. This is a `forOf` loop. Consider `foreach` in C#, it works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, try this:

```
<p *ngFor="let history of histories; let i=index; "
[ngClass]="{'show':history.date==dateseeing}">
    <span class="history-date">{{ history.date }}</span>
    <span class="history-txt">{{ history.txt }}</span>
    <mat-icon 
        *ngIf="history.date==dateseeing"
        (click)="readNext(histories[i+1])">keyboard_arrow_down
    </mat-icon></p>
```

You can't do `history[i]` as history is your item from array and you want to access the second item from `histories` array